# using template div id in an angular if statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I have a modal with 3 lists that have unique ids:

```
<p class="accordion" ng-class"{active:accordion==2}" ng-click="accordion = 2">COPY from the PARCEL:</p>
<ul class="related_email_list accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==2">
    <li ng-repeat="address in parcelAddressToStk">
        <label for="selectAddress_parcel_{{address.AddressID}}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{address.Alternate}}" class="parcelAddress" id="selectAddress_parcel_{{address.AddressID}}" value="{{address}}" ng-click="selectedAddresses(address);" ng-model="address.isSelected" ng-options="address.AddressID as address.pseudo for address in parcelAddressToStk" />
            <span>
                <b class="int-name">{{address.AddressType==='Mailing'?'Mailing Address:':(address.AddressType==='Street'?'Parcel Address:':(address.AddressType==='Mailing/Street'?'Mailing/Street Address:':'Home Quarter Address:'))}} </b>
                <b>{{address.Alternate}}</b>
                <b>{{address.StreetNumber?address.StreetNumber+" ":""}}{{address.StreetDirPre?address.StreetDirPre+" ":""}}{{address.StreetName?address.StreetName+" ":""}}{{address.StreetType?address.StreetType+" ":""}}{{address.StreetDirSuf?address.StreetDirSuf+" ":""}}{{address.UnitNumber!==""?"Unit " + address.UnitNumber:""}}</b>
                <b>{{address.Municipality?address.Municipality+" ":""}}{{address.SubDivisionCode?address.SubDivisionCode+" ":""}}{{address.PCODE?address.PCODE+" ":""}}{{address.PostalZip?address.PostalZip+" ":""}}</b>
            </span>
         </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to know if it's possible to use the `selectAddress_parcel_{ID}` in an if statement. I've tried

```
if ($scope["selectAddress_parcel_" + item.AddressID] == true) {
//do something
}
```

which comes back as undefined in the watch list.  But if I hard-code `selectAddress_parcel_56088` in watch I can see the correct object.

Is there an easier way to do this or am I concatenating my if statement incorrectly?

Comment: have you tried `var myScope = "selectAddress_parcel_" + item.AddressID.toString(); if ($scope[myScope] == true) {...`

Comment: returns string "selectAddress_parcel_56088" but no object

Comment: Okay, I though you were hardcoding a string not a variable. try this `if ($scope[eval("selectAddress_parcel_" + item.AddressID)] == true)`

Comment: No luck.  I'm going to use the ng-click event instead.  thanks for your help